# Adding values to a LiveChart c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a LiveChart which displays the graphic of a certain function , let's take for eaxmple cos(x) , I'm adding the values of the function in a List while looping through a `for` loop , which takes `a` as the start ,`b` as the end and `delta` as the incrementation, I can't figure out how can I add the list which has the values of the function to the LiveChart , I tried to search it on the internet but I can't find anything.
Could someone please show me how it can be done ?

CODE :

```
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace Lab1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void submitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cartesianChart.Series.Clear();
        SeriesCollection series = new SeriesCollection();
        double a = Convert.ToDouble(valueOfA.Text);
        double b = Convert.ToDouble(valueOfB.Text);
        double delta = Convert.ToDouble(valueOfDelta.Text);
        List<double> values = new List<double>();
        for (double x=a;x<=b;x+=delta)
        {
            values.Add(Math.Cos(x));
            series.Add();
        }
        //MessageBox.Show($"Values of A, B and Delta are : {a} , {b} , {delta}");
    }
}
}
```

XAML :

```
<Window
    
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
    compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lab1"
    xmlns:Wpf="clr- 
    namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf" 
    x:Class="Lab1.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
               Text="GRAPH" FontSize="36" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
               Text="A" FontSize="30"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
               Text="B" FontSize="30"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"
               Text="Δ" FontSize="30"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="valueOfA" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
             Width="80" Height="30"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="valueOfB" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"
             Width="80" Height="30"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="valueOfDelta" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4"
             Width="80" Height="30"/>
    <Button x:Name="submitButton" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"
            Width="150" Height="30" Content="START" Margin="10,10" 
Click="submitButton_Click"/>
    <Wpf:CartesianChart x:Name="cartesianChart" Grid.Column="4" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="345.6,5.4,0,0" 
Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
        <Wpf:CartesianChart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="364" 
Margin="-301,-136,-48,-128" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="449"/>
    </Wpf:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML for the chart?

Comment: @Darren_D19 I've added the XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the values that you were looping through to be displayed in a chart which is what I think you wanted from reading your question. This is a very simple answer and does not set up the formatting of tooltips or Axis, I will leave you to do that and if you get stuck you can post another question and tag me.

**XAML** :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:Wpf="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
    FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}">

<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="GRAPH" FontSize="36" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="A" FontSize="30"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="B" FontSize="30"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="Δ" FontSize="30"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="valueOfA" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Width="80" Height="30"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="valueOfB" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Width="80" Height="30"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="valueOfDelta" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Width="80" Height="30"/>
    <Button x:Name="submitButton" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Width="150" Height="30" Content="START" Margin="10,10" Click="submitButton_Click"/>

    <Wpf:CartesianChart x:Name="cartesianChart" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="7">

        <Wpf:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="7"/>

    </Wpf:CartesianChart>

</Grid>
```

**Code behind** :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Series 1",
                Values = new ChartValues<double>()
            }
        };
    }

    private void submitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double a = Convert.ToDouble(valueOfA.Text);
        double b = Convert.ToDouble(valueOfB.Text);
        double delta = Convert.ToDouble(valueOfDelta.Text);
        List<double> values = new List<double>();

        for (double x = a; x <= b; x += delta)
        {
            values.Add(Math.Cos(x));
        }

        foreach(var value in values)
        {
            SeriesCollection[0].Values.Add(value);
        }

        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SeriesCollection"));

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

}
```

**Result** :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much , I know understand how the chart works m I tried searching it on the internet but couldn't find a thing

Comment: @MohammedHamdoon I am not sure if you checked out the official documentation, there is a lot of tutorials and samples. Here is a link https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/Wpf/Line